# MySQL associated table COUNT() and GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, count, group-by

I am doing a pretty normal routine, but having a tough time getting my output correct.

**I have two tables:** *ads_list* (listings) and *ads_cate* (categories).

I am currently displaying my category list like so:

```
SELECT id, cateName FROM ads_cate ORDER BY cateName
```

**What I am trying to achieve:** count of all items in each category in this format:

Category  |  Number of Ads

categoryName 56

**This is my current code**, and have been tweaking but getting no output in my array:

```
SELECT 

ads_cate.id, 
ads_cate.cateName, // Category Name

ads_list.id, 
ads_list.COUNT(title), // Title of ad
ads_list.Category // Relational Category ID INT(11)

FROM

ads_cate, 
ads_list

GROUP BY cateName 
ORDER BY cateName
```

I am calling in all required fields and running a COUNT() on my title field (as these are unique for each ad) and then I am grouping by cateName which also seems correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See what this gives you. I think it is what you need.

```
SELECT 
ads_cate.cateName, // Category Name
COUNT(ads_list.id), // Title of ad
FROM

ads_cate
INNER JOIN 
ads_list
ON ads_cate.id = ads_list.category

GROUP BY cateName 
ORDER BY cateName
```

Comment: NullRef, I see the JOIN was probably very important in my equation. I changed ads_list.COUNT(ads_cate.id) to ads_list.COUNT(ads_list.title), but I am still facing the same problem. I cannot get any output in my print_r() for this query? When I run my original query I get output. The ONLY think I am changing is the query. I tested to ensure it was the query and it is. Something in my new queries is not getting any table data.. I'm in mystery.

Comment: NullRef, thanks for your tips! I think I need to create a new thread on my other issue. It seems the MySQL version I am running does not like COUNT()!

Comment: @OldWest realized I had a couple typos. Fixed. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, NullRef but still the same problem. I should also note I tripe and double checked all field names to ensure they are spelled correct on my end..